# « N'importe en qui » : en ?

Tags: prépositions, locutions, québec, syntaxe, pronoms-interrogatifs

> C'était un monsieur dans la cinquantaine quand i est venu s'établir au
> village, pas loin de l'église dans a rue qui vient aboutir au lac. I
> était veuf. I passait pour être en moyens. En par cas i avait pas de
> métier ni aucune sorte de profession. C'est pas **n'importe en qui** qui
> pouvait rentrer chez eux.
>
> [ [Claude-Henri Grignon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude-Henri_Grignon), *Le père bougonneux*, ds. Le bulletin des
> agriculteurs, mars 1954 (avec un parler de la fin du 19e au Québec), à la p. 112, je souligne ]

[*N'importe qui*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%E2%80%99importe_qui) (aussi avec *quoi, quand, comment, où* etc.) est une locution pronominale indéfinie figée et après 1850 il est rare et archaïque d'évoquer le tour primitif en faisant précéder le mot interrogatif de la préposition qui normalement précèdera le tout le cas échéant (LBU14 § 379 a).

— N'importe PAR quel moyen (Ac., 1835 et 1878)
— L'habitude qu'il avait prise de dormir n'importe SUR quelle planche (Sand).
— Elle rachèterait la maison n'importe À quel prix (Zola).

---

L'exemple e Grignon correspond-il à l'emploi rare et archaïque qui précède et si oui, pourquoi *en*, quelle est sa fonction, à quel verbe se rattache-t-il et s'agit-il de la préposition ? Sinon à quel phénomène rattache-t-on la présence du « en » dans ce type de locution (*n'importe en qui, n'importe en quoi*) chez les personnages de Grignon au Québec ?

Answer (score 3):

En voyant le reste du texte, je pense que c'est simplement la transcription d'un accent, probablement campagnard.

On trouve aussi plusieurs fois *i* au lieu de *il* et un *a* au lieu de *la*, et la phrase a tout son sens avec comprenant "n'importe qui" donc j'opterais pour ça.

Comment: C'est possible mais quand tu regardes ces [résultats](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22n%27importe+en+qui%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiExLvIl6v3AhUCHM0KHVfjBRwQ_AUoAXoECAIQCw&biw=1920&bih=955&dpr=1), même si c'est juste un ou deux tu vois _Jean Guillaume César Alexandre Hippolyte de Colins_ (Belgique) et _Antoine-Vincent Arnault_ (France) au 19e dans des contextes où le ton campagnard est fort peu probable...

Comment: @Earendelle Je n'ai pas trouvé ces exemples précisément, mais dans les autres occurrences que j'ai trouvé, la phrase était assez différente et c'était dans un sens de "*peu importe en ...*". Ex. : "*n'importe en quoi vous croyez*", ou "*l'onction invisible [...], n'importe en qui elle se trouve, ...*". Ce sens n'est pas possible dans la phrase de la question.

Comment: « L'autocratie, telle que la raison ordonne qu'elle soit, n'importe en qui et n'importe où, est nécessaire, absolument nécessaire, pour que l'humanité ne périsse point au sein de l'anarchie. » (Colins) ; « Les hommes ne sont que trop portés à honorer et à invoquer la puissance, n'importe en qui elle se trouve » (Arnault), cette dernière phrase ressemble à _peu importe_. Mais les personnages populaires de Grignon emploient aussi des trucs comme _En seulement_, incluant en début de phrase, pour _sauf que_. Je pense que c'est un truc syntaxique archaïque, mais quelle est sa fonction, ça...

Answer (score 1):

Dans la phrase proposée (contrairement à celle de Zola), "en" n'est pas une préposition qui serait présente dans la formulation moderne : on ne dirait pas "ce n'est pas en n'importe qui qui pouvait rentrer chez eux", mais plutôt "ce n'était pas n'importe qui qui pouvait" (le doublement du "qui" n'est pas du meilleur effet mais la formulation est correcte).

Il doit donc effectivement s'agir de la transcription d'une façon de parler locale, dans laquelle une erreur phonétique s'est fixée dans l'usage courant (de la même façon que certaines personnes disent et écrivent aujourd'hui "combien même" au lieu de "quand bien même").

Comment: Oui mais, voir le [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50180/nimporte-en-qui-en#comment103904_50186) sous l'autre réponse. Peu de résultats mais à l'écrit et dans des contextes différents.